# Office 365 VBA Error 53 DLL file not found

Tags: excel, vba, dll, runtime-error, office365

I routinely call Fortran compiled DLLs from VBA in Excel, but with Office365 I get the Error 53 'DLL file not found". With other versions of office, I either store the DLL in the 'current' directory (e.g. where Excel last saved a file to), or in one of the system directories such as C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office 16\1033. However, the first does not appear to work with Office365, and I cannot find a suitable system folder to store the DLL in with Office365. 
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Always helps to include the code you're using.

Comment: Sorry - didn't want to distract from the real problem. The code is standard: "Private Declare Sub IMPACT Lib "Impact4-2-32bit" (ByRef Par1 etc " (or a 64bit version according to system).